# Load all relation to a single user laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I like to get everything related to user

```
$this->storeproducts = User::find($x)->with(['stores.inventories.product'])->first();
```

But that don't work as user has not stores table i think (assumption). It shows all users relation all 5 register find($x) don't make any difference.

```
#items: array:5 [▼
    0 => App\Models\User {#1432 ▶}
    1 => App\Models\User {#1433 ▶}
    2 => App\Models\User {#1448 ▶}
    3 => App\Models\User {#1449 ▶}
    4 => App\Models\User {#1450 ▶}
  ]
```

that i don't want that i **want only that user related details(relations)**

```
3 => App\Models\User {#1449 ▼
      #fillable: array:3 [▶]
      #hidden: array:4 [▶]
      #casts: array:1 [▶]
      #appends: array:1 [▶]
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "users"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      +preventsLazyLoading: false
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:14 [▶]
      #original: array:14 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #classCastCache: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: array:1 [▼
        "stores" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1453 ▼
          #items: array:1 [▼
            0 => App\Models\Store {#1458 ▼
              #fillable: array:6 [▶]
              #connection: "mysql"
              #table: "stores"
              #primaryKey: "id"
              #keyType: "int"
              +incrementing: true
              #with: []
              #withCount: []
              +preventsLazyLoading: false
              #perPage: 15
              +exists: true
              +wasRecentlyCreated: false
              #attributes: array:8 [▶]
              #original: array:8 [▶]
              #changes: []
              #casts: []
              #classCastCache: []
              #dates: []
              #dateFormat: null
              #appends: []
              #dispatchesEvents: []
              #observables: []
              #relations: array:1 [▼
                "inventories" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1469 ▼
                  #items: array:1 [▼
                    0 => App\Models\Inventory {#1467 ▼
                      #fillable: array:3 [▶]
                      #connection: "mysql"
                      #table: "inventories"
                      #primaryKey: "id"
                      #keyType: "int"
                      +incrementing: true
                      #with: []
                      #withCount: []
                      +preventsLazyLoading: false
                      #perPage: 15
                      +exists: true
                      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
                      #attributes: array:6 [▶]
                      #original: array:6 [▶]
                      #changes: []
                      #casts: []
                      #classCastCache: []
                      #dates: []
                      #dateFormat: null
                      #appends: []
                      #dispatchesEvents: []
                      #observables: []
                      #relations: array:1 [▼
                        "product" => App\Models\Product {#1474 ▼
                          #fillable: array:5 [▶]
                          #connection: "mysql"
                          #table: "products"
                          #primaryKey: "id"
                          #keyType: "int"
                          +incrementing: true
                          #with: []
                          #withCount: []
                          +preventsLazyLoading: false
                          #perPage: 15
                          +exists: true
                          +wasRecentlyCreated: false
                          #attributes: array:8 [▶]
                          #original: array:8 [▶]
                          #changes: []
                          #casts: []
                          #classCastCache: []
                          #dates: []
                          #dateFormat: null
                          #appends: []
                          #dispatchesEvents: []
                          #observables: []
                          #relations: []
                          #touches: []
                          +timestamps: true
                          #hidden: []
                          #visible: []
                          #guarded: array:1 [▶]
                        }
                      ]
                      #touches: []
                      +timestamps: true
                      #hidden: []
                      #visible: []
                      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
              #touches: []
              +timestamps: true
              #hidden: []
              #visible: []
              #guarded: array:1 [▶]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
```

Relation are on User(model)

```
public function stores(){
    return $this->hasMany(Store::class);
}
```

Relation are on Store(model)

```
public function inventories() {
    return $this->hasMany(inventory::class);
}
```

Relation are on Inventory(model)

```
public function product() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we load all relation of User model before choose user we need. You could try the following code:

```
$this->storeproducts = User::with(['stores.inventories.product'])->find($x);
```

Comment: You should include *why* they should try your code... Why does it solve the problem?

Comment: @BrianThompson Thank you for pointing out. I correct it.

Answer (score 2):

`find($id)` is equivalent to `where('id', $id)->first()` so with find, you already have a collection, not a query builder

change it to

```
User::where('id', $x)->with(['stores.inventories.product'])->first();
//or
User::with(['stores.inventories.product'])->find($x);
```